# Craft 3 Plugin: Unable to add a new method to EntryQuery

Tags: plugin-development, craft3

I am developing a Craft 3 plugin and would need to add a new method like 

`{% for item in craft.entries.section('sectionName').birthday('XYZ123').all() %}`

According to doc https://docs.craftcms.com/v3/element-types.html#element-query-class, I am using following code:

File: `/by/prefix/element/Birthdate.php`

`<?php
    namespace by\prefix\elements;
    use craft\base\Element;
    use craft\elements\db\ElementQueryInterface;
    use by\prefix\elements\db\BirthdateQuery;
    class Birthdate extends Element
    {
        public $birthdate;
        public static function find(): ElementQueryInterface
        {

            return new BirthdateQuery(static::class);
        }
    }`

File: `/by/prefix/element/db/BirthdateQuery.php`

`<?php
    namespace by\tariffsinfo\elements\db;
    use craft;
    use craft\db\Query;
    use craft\elements\db\ElementQuery;
    use craft\helpers\Db;
    use by\tariffsinfo\elements\BirthdateElement;
    class BirthdateQuery extends ElementQuery
    {
        public $birthdate;
        public function birthdate($value)
        {

            return $value;
        }
    }`

and I am getting error message: 
`Calling unknown method: craft\elements\db\EntryQuery::birthdate()`

Could anyone please help what am I doing wrong.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You know you don't add a new function to Crafts `EntryQuery` you create a custom `Element` type with a custom `Query` and add a function to that one. By the way you should probably fix your `namespaces`

```
use by\prefix\elements\db\BirthdateQuery;
use by\tariffsinfo\elements\BirthdateElement;
```

In order to use your function you'll have to do

```
BirthdateElement::find()->birthdate('whatever');
```

To search for a custom field in an entries `FieldLayout` you just need to call the parameter by handle... So when you include a field into the layout with the handle `birthday` you can do

```
{% set entries = craft.entries.birthday('whatever').all() %}
```

When you want to search for your custom element type in your frontend you'll have to include a function to Twig like Craft does

```
/**
 * Returns a new EntryQuery instance.
 *
 * @param mixed $criteria
 * @return EntryQuery
 */
public function birthdays($criteria = null): BirthdateQuery
{
    $query = BirthdateElement::find();
    if ($criteria) {
        Craft::configure($query, $criteria);
    }

    return $query;
}
```

So you can access it via

```
{% set birthdates = craft.pluginName.birthdays.id(2).birthdate('whatever').all() %}
```